# Is there a way to make the gca method from matplotlib work?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

**The configuration:**

> - Mac OS
> - vs code
> - python-3.x

**The Error:**

*the code:*

```py
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
surf1 = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=2, cstride=2, cmap=mpl.cm.coolwarm, linewidth=0.5, antialiased=True) # Plots the original function surface 
surf2 = ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z, rstride=2, cstride=2, label='regression') # Plots the regression surface
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('f(x, y)')
ax.legend()
fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)
```

*The error message:*

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In\[61\], line 2
1 fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
2 ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
3 surf1 = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=2, cstride=2, cmap=mpl.cm.coolwarm, linewidth=0.5, antialiased=True) # Plots the original function surface
4 surf2 = ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z, rstride=2, cstride=2, label='regression') # Plots the regression surface

TypeError: FigureBase.gca() got an unexpected keyword argument 'projection'
<Figure size 1000x600 with 0 Axes>
```

I was  trying to obtain this image: (please see image below)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The workaround I use for the moment is the following:

```py
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
```

Which gives the following code:

```py
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
surf1 = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=2, cstride=2, cmap=mpl.cm.coolwarm, linewidth=0.5, antialiased=True) # Plots the original function surface 
surf2 = ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z, rstride=2, cstride=2, label='regression') # Plots the regression surface
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('f(x, y)')
ax.legend()
fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)
```

But I would prefer to find the solution to make the gca work.

Comment: This isn't a "workaround".  It is the correct way, as shown in the [official examples](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/index.html).  `gca()` isn't meant to create a new subplot, it is meant to access the "current" subplot (usually the latest created). A side effect of calling `gca` when no subplot has been created yet, is that `gca` internally calls `add_subplot` with default parameters.